# Regex match for number within parenthesis separated by comma

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate following type of number with a regular expression

```
(1, 2, 33, 1, 63)
(1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12312, 41)
(512,    41, 7,     2, 9)
6, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3
(6, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3,)
(, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3)
(,6, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3)
()
```

Each number should be followed by a comma then any number of spaces.

I tried something like this

```
[\(]+[\d]*[\,][\s]*[\)]+
```

But I do not know how to proceed furher

Comment: Which one is valid and which one is not valid?

Comment: FYI: Your current regex has a lot of unnecessary stuff in it. If you remove that you get: `\(+\d*,\s*\)+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each number should be followed by a comma then any number of spaces.

Use:

```
\((\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*)\)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last `?` be a `*`?